# How should i store questions and answers in mysql table design

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I have following tables

1. User
2. Question
3. QuestionCategories
4. Answers

NOw i am confused whether my user class should have any link to questions or just answers

User will answer the question shown on the form.

So every year there will different answers for different questions

Comment: You need to give more details on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it makes sense depending on what you want to do. Is a user able to post a question? If yes, link it. If not, linking doesnt make sense because it would stay emty.

Comment: my questions are fixed and can not be asked by users , they can nly answer them and answer will be different every year. its like feedback form which user can fill every year

Comment: Ok, so i don't see a need for linking these. If you want to know which user replied to a certain question, you can do this by going the way question -> answer -> user. (that just means to join all 3 tables and set a where condition)

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume a user can ask a question, a question can belong to a category, and a number of users can post answers. It's about what a site like stackoverflow is like, actually.

```
create table user (
  user_id integer primary key,
  name varchar(40) not null
);

create table category (
  category_id integer primary key,
  category varchar(40) not null
);

create table question (
  question_id integer primary key,
  question text,
  asked_by_id integer not null,
  category_id integer not null,
  foreign key asked_by_id references user(user_id),
  foreign key category_id references categor(category_id)
);

create table answer (
  answers_id     integer not null,
  answered_by_id integer not null,
  answer text,
  primary key (answers_id, answered_by_id), -- we allow one answer per person for a question
  foreign key answers_id references question(question_id),
  foreign key answered_by_id references user(user_id)
);
```

And then the query:

```
select qu.name as asked_by,    question, category,
       au.name as answered_by, answer
from user qu                                       -- iterating through users
join question q on qu.user_id    = asked_by_id     -- joining them to their questions
join category c on c.category_id = q.category_id   -- find the category
join answer     on answers_id    = question_id     -- join by what answers this question
join user au    on au.user_id    = answered_by_id; -- looking up the user who answered it
```

(I didn't try it on a server so there might be typos. Feel free to correct.)

Comment: I'd add relation between question and answer (one to many assuming the question can have multiple answers)

Comment: True, but it's just an example. I added categories (I forgot them at first), and for those I assumed a question can only have one. So now there's an example for both kinds of relations.

Comment: Minras wait, I misunderstood what you wrote. That *already* is a one to many relation -- check the foreign keys: answers_id is *not* the answer_id (I have no such thing) but a reference to a question that it answers.

Comment: Yep, sorry, you are right. But in that case I'd create a simple primary key for answers, because current implementation limits the user to leave only one answer for a question. Composite primary key is a good feature, but I think it's over-engineering in this case.

Comment: Yes, that was a random design decision =) In a Q&A I'd assume if one answers a question, he would edit that same question if he changes his mind. For a forum, yes: I would allow multiple responses for the same user.

Comment: Well, it's arguable decision, but +1 anyway.

Comment: my questions are fixed and can not be asked by users , they can nly answer them and answer will be different every year. its like feedback form which user can fill every year

Answer (score -1):

instead of updating multiple rows, you can simply convert your questions along with their options and answers into json and store as a single field.